# Does anyone know of a vim plugin or script to convert special characters to their corresponding HTML entities?

Tags: vim

I develop websites for corporate clients, so we see the ®, ™, etc. chars a whole lot. Sometimes I paste in huge blocks of copy, which might even contain pretty quotes (“ ”) or other strange characters from word processors.

So, my question is this: Does anyone know of a vim plugin or script that can, in one fell swoop, convert all these characters to html entities?

I think this covers all the bases of the entities it would be nice to have:
http://web.forret.com/tools/charmap.asp

So, for the characters above, they would be replaced with `&reg;`, `&trade;`, `&ldquo;`, `&rdquo;`, etc.

I tried the htmlspecialchars vimball (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2377), but no dice. It only performs its replacement like the PHP htmlsepcialchars function, replacing html-conflicting characters, and doesn't cover any additional special characters.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? HTML entities are sort of deprecated. Current HTML 4 and 5 support extended Unicode characters directly into the document body, and XHTML and XML already dropped support for these entities (keeping only the 5 basic XML entities). Just create proper HTML, with DOCTYPE and specified charset, serve the file with the correct charset and you won't need any HTML entity.

Comment: Great point. I kind of doubted whether or not this worked across the board, so I did some tests across different browsers in virtual machines, and it definitely seems like there is full support in all modern browsers if the document has valid DOCTYPE and charset. Thanks so much. I never realized this was a non-issue. You just saved me a TON of time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend Tim Pope's [unimpaired](http://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired/blob/master/doc/unimpaired.txt#L63-73) plugin. It provides [commands to encode and decode html entities](http://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired/blob/a59a121ee6fd7337a5b3a115aba32de6fbf5f0b2/doc/unimpaired.txt#L57-73), using the mappings: `[x` and `]x` respectively.

Comment: This plugin is so useful, I recommend it!

Answer (score 2):

Perl is better for this sort of things. Paste your file into vim and run this:

```
:%!perl -p -i -e 'BEGIN { use Encode; } $_=Encode::decode_utf8($_) unless Encode::is_utf8($_); $_=Encode::encode("ascii", $_, Encode::FB_HTMLCREF);'
```

Or even better:

```
%!perl -p -i -e 'BEGIN { use HTML::Entities; use Encode; } $_=Encode::decode_utf8($_) unless Encode::is_utf8($_); $_=Encode::encode("ascii", $_, sub{HTML::Entities::encode_entities(chr shift)});'
```

(HTML::Entities is a part of HTML::Parser on my system)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this as a macro, something like this in your .vimrc (i'll let you fill in the rest of the entities ;-) ):

```
let @a=':%s/á/\&aacute;/g^M:%s/é/\&eacute;/g^M:%s/í/\&iacute;/g^M ... '
```

note that ^M is a special character entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I was as surprised as you are that Vim can't do this and no plugins (not even unimpaired.vim) can convert all HTML entities.

[So I made a plugin](https://github.com/DelvarWorld/vim-html-entities)!

Usage: in normal mode, `]he<motion>` to convert the character included in the motion to their proper HTML entities. Will convert (almost any) character.