# HTML::Entities encoding and single ampersand

Tags: html, perl, vim, cpan

I'm attempting to use the following line of perl, as described here:  [Does anyone know of a vim plugin or script to convert special characters to their corresponding HTML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054971/does-anyone-know-of-a-vim-plugin-or-script-to-convert-special-characters-to-their) - to encode HTML entities in Vim.

```
%!perl -p -i -e 'BEGIN { use HTML::Entities; use Encode; } $_=Encode::decode_utf8($_) unless Encode::is_utf8($_);  $_=Encode::encode("ascii", $_, sub{HTML::Entities::encode_entities(chr shift)});'
```

It works fine (£ to &pound, curly quotes etc.) except for an ampersand on it's own - & - which is left as it is.

I've tried removing the uf8 decoding, and looked at the CPAN documentation for HTML::Entities.

**Answer:**

@ZyX has answered the original question, but as others have pointed out in the comments, this is redundant as it's not actually necessary to use HTML entities if you are serving pages with a UTF-8 character set (which I am, both with the meta tag -

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

and also in the Apache configuration:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Indeed it's arguably a bad thing adding them in such cases; the filesize is bigger and the text is obfuscated should anyway want to make use of the source code.

It's essential you ensure whatever editor(s) you use to create files are writing them in UTF-8 as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why you are doing this in the first place?

Comment: I am learning Vim - frequently have to convert Word documents and other sources with smart quotes, apostrophes, currencies etc. to properly formatted HTML.  Spent a while searching for Vim plugins - there didn't seem a great deal of consensus on them and I liked the Perl approach someone suggested as it (a) was quite short (b) used HTML::Entities rather than reinventing the wheel, which many people seem to have tried to..

Comment: Ah, fair enough. (In 90% of all cases, people use entities to work around encoding problems, in which case my standard answer is "fix the encoding problem instead", hence my question.) The problem is that in HTML, the ampersand is the escape character for entities. So every *real* ampersand needs to be escaped as `&amp;`. Not sure what the best way to fix it is in this case though, I'm not familiar with these tools

Comment: @Pekka: I think this counts amongst the 90% of all cases! Smart quotes, apostrophes, currencies etc absolutely *are* properly-formatted HTML included verbatim in a UTF-8 document and should not be entity-encoded unless there's a specific need to—typically for interoperability with editors that don't grok Unicode, which are thankfully vanishingly few.

Comment: @bobince good to know - I'm not entirely up to speed on what kinds of character sets can be present in a Word document. In that case @williamt there is the question whether what you want to do is necessary at all :)

Comment: @bobince @Pekka Thanks - had completely missed until today that specifying UTF-8 removed the need for HTML entities at all - they were something I learned years ago and have blindly persisted with since. Now I know this it'll save me a lot of time...

Comment: @williamt: Using `set fileencoding` in vimrc is pointless: its value will be overwritten after reading a file. You should set 'fileencodings' to the correct value (or set it to empty string if you want 'fileencoding' setting in vimrc to have effect).

Comment: @Zyx Thanks. I've removed that line - seemed overly confusing given Vim has 'encoding', 'fileencoding' and 'fileencodings' variables.  It seems safe enough to rely on 'locale' being set correctly and ensure you proofread webpages with the 'meta charset' specified (but again, correct me if I'm wrong..)

Comment: @williamt Charset in meta does not have any effect unless you have a plugin that reopens file if charset specified in meta does not match fileencoding (it is really used only for writing, but I don't know any way how to get encoding used for reading a file. 'fileencoding' is first set when file was read to the encoding used for reading, but may be overwritten later).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer was only encoding characters that are above ascii range. If you want to encode something as html, you should use

```
$text=HTML::Entities::encode_entities($text);
```

:

```
%!perl -MHTML::Entities -MEncode -p -i -e '$_=Encode::decode_utf8($_) unless Encode::is_utf8($_); $_=HTML::Entities::encode_entities($_);'
```

I was not using this in that answer because TS only requested to encode unicode characters without encoding `<`, `>`, `&` as well.

By the way, you may use `$text=HTML::Entities::encode_entities($text, '<>&"');` to encode only really unsafe characters (though I guess this is easily expressed with vimscript:

```
:let entities={'<': 'lt', '>': 'gt', '&': 'amp', '"': 'quot'}
:execute '%s/['.escape(join(keys(entities), ''), '\-]^').']/\="&".entities[submatch(0)].";"/g'
```

Comment: I want to echo the recommendation to encode only really unsafe characters.

Answer (score -1):

```
perl -MHTML::Entities -i -e 'print encode_entities shift'
```

should work, doesn't it?

Comment: No. First, guess why I used `Encode::decode_utf8`? Second, you are operating on the next argument to perl, while you need to operate on given files or stdout.

Comment: Well, I took your -i command as granted, and as necessary for your Vim stuff. Second, it certainly works fine when I pipe from a file with -n. I mean your problem was with &, wasn't it. I do get &amp;

Comment: @i-blis 1. I failed to get any results by running `echo '&' | perl -MHTML::Entities -i -e 'print encode_entities shift'`, though I can get them by running `perl -MHTML::Entities -i -e 'print encode_entities shift' '&'`. 2. It was not *my* problem. 3. Try to encode any multibyte unicode character in this fashion and see what happens (may be dependent on perl version, I heard something about unicode changes in most recent perl).

Comment: @ZyX 1. I know the behaviour with -i, thanks. I provided the oneliner in the same form as in the question.  2. Sorry about that. 3. Apparently no problem encoding multibyte unicode characters (without explicit decoding) with Perl 5.12 (I tested with UTF-8 encoded Russian).

Comment: @i-blis 3. Are you sure? `perl -MHTML::Entities -i -e 'print encode_entities shift' '«»'` results in `&Acirc;&laquo;&Acirc;&raquo;`, while no `&Acirc;` should be present. If you add `-MEncode` and `decode_utf8` everything is normal. I guess you have non-unicode locale: when I use `LANG=ru_RU.CP1251 perl -MHTML::Entities -i -e 'print encode_entities shift' $(echo «» | iconv -f utf-8 -t cp1251)` it produces result as expected (I should really have used `use open qw(:locale)` instead of decoding utf8 but I was not aware of non-unicode locales).

Comment: @ZyX, I did not even know that the console I tested on had the locale set to ru_RU.KOI8-R. I drove crazy when I was not able to reproduce it on my own machine (en_GB.UTF-8). So yes, encoding multibyte unicode does require decoding. My apologies for failing testing.